# The distinction between the Orwell's belief about real world and his imagination

Tags: meaning, george-orwell, nineteen-eighty-four, anthony-burgess, nineteen-eighty-five

> Orwell seemed to believe that the real world, as opposed to that of
> his feverish and genuinely diseased imagination, was moving in the
> direction of bigger and worse cacotopias.
>
> 1985 by Anthony Burgess

Here Anthony Burgess makes a remark about Orwells belief. As I understand Burgess says that Orwell thinks that real world is moving towards cacotopias. And Orwell's imagination is opposed to this.

But in the book "1984" we see that Orwell's imagination too shows the same. So in 1984 the world is cacotopian. And also moves to worse cacotopias.

So why Burgess says that "Orwell's belief is opposed to this imagination"?

Answer (score 2):

'As opposed to' Does not mean the same as 'opposed to'.
It is a set phrase which carries the meaning '[distinguished from or in contrast with](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22as%20opposed%20to%22&rlz=1C1GCEB_enGB890GB890&oq=%22as%20opposed%20to%22&gs_lcrp=EgZjaHJvbWUyBggAEEUYOTIHCAEQABiABDIHCAIQABiABDIHCAMQABiABDIHCAQQABiABDIHCAUQABiABDIHCAYQABiABDIHCAcQABiABDIHCAgQABiABDIHCAkQABiABNIBCDM4MjBqMGo0qAIAsAIA&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)'. The 'or' in that definition is important as it tells us that it is not necessary for something that is 'as opposed to' something else is in contrast, it is enough that it is distinguished from it.
This is the sense that is being used by Burgess, he is making clear that he, Burgess, is not confusing Orwell's imagined world with Orwell's understanding of the real world. The fact that both of those worlds may be headed in the same direction makes the need for distinguishing between them stronger.